# Form Submission & JavaScript not working in IE, Firefox, or Safari; works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Okay.  I've got a form that, when submitted, goes through JavaScript to decide what page to take the user to next.

Everything works fine when I preview it in my IDE (Coda 2), and when I preview in Chrome.  However, when I open the same page in Firefox, IE (any version), or Safari, I can't get past the first page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link href="eh_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav id="navWrapper" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand">Site Title</a>
                </div>
                <div class="link-container">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://www.link.net">LinkText</a></li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:support@link.net?subject:Help”>Help</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="page-container">
                <form onsubmit="OpenWindow()" id="page1" action="" method="post">
                    <fieldset id="mainSelection">
                        <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="A" name="sel1"> Option A</label><br />
                        <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="B" name="sel1"> Option B</label><br />
                        <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="C" name="sel1"> Option C</label><br />
                        <label><input type="radio" class="radio-button" value="D" name="sel1"> Option D</label><br />
                    </fieldset><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton" form="page1">
                </form>
            </div><!--page-container-->
        </div><!--main-container-->
        <footer class="site-footer">
            Footer Text
        </footer>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function OpenWindow() {
                var choice = document.getElementById("page1");
                choice = choice.sel1.value;

                if (choice == 'A') {
                    window.open('result1.html','_self');
                } else if (choice == 'B') {
                    window.open('page2.html','_self');
                } else if (choice == 'C') {
                    window.open('page3.html','_self');
                } else if (choice == 'D') {
                    window.open('page4.html','_self');
                }
                return: false;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have no idea what's going on here.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Per several suggestions, I've added a `return: false;` statement to the end of my script, but things still aren't working properly.

Comment: Hit F12. Go to the script debugger. Debug your page. (Also, your openWindow function should return false)

Comment: I'm intrigued by the fact you included jquery in the page but resorted to pure JS in the code

But my guess would be that as EricLaw mentioned, because your openwindow function isn't returning false the form is submitting the data to the same page.

Comment: @user1094553 This is the second time I've ever messed with JS - I wasn't sure if I needed to include jQuery or not to get it to run properly.

Comment: @EricLaw I've got the Firefox debug window open. Before adding `return: false;` to the bottom of my script, when I submitted the form it would open the function, but just hang on a Loading message. 

After adding `return: false;`, it populates the URL field with `javascript:OpenWindow()` and prints `false` on the display...any ideas?

Comment: @user1094553 see last comment.

Comment: @EricLaw any ideas? I've added the `return: false;` and removed the jQuery library, but I'm still not getting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, just use this to get the value:

```
var choice = $('.radio-button:checked').val();
```

and remove the

```
var choice = document.getElementById("page1");
choice = choice.sel1.value;
```

Not sure why, but IE wasn't recognizing the "choice.sel1.value".  And also, you need to fix this if you want to keep "return false", though I don't think it's needed:

```
return: false;
```

should be

```
else
{
return false;
}
```

I also removed onsubmit="OpenWindow()" and changed the action to "javascript:OpenWindow()" and that worked for me.  Good luck!

Comment: you've done it.  

This seems to be working in IE11 (there's a small glitch where it won't work the first time, but on a second try it works)- I'll test in other browsers to confirm.

Comment: glitch was my fault; I didn't remove the `onsubmit` option from the form declaration. 

Now works across all browsers.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Great!  jQuery is so helpful.  Glad it's working for you

Answer (score 0):

Problem is right here:

```
<form onsubmit="OpenWindow()" id="page1" action="" method="post">
```

Change to `action=""` from `action="javascript:OpenWindow()"`

A form action set to a JavaScript function is not supported by many browsers. I am surprised it is supported by Chrome.

**EDIT**

JS:

```
function OpenWindow() {
var choice = $('input[name="sel1"]:checked').val();
        if (choice == 'A') {
            window.open('http://youtube.com','_self');
        } else if (choice == 'B') {
            window.open('http://facebook.com','_self');
        } else if (choice == 'C') {
            window.open('http://twitter.com','_self');
        } else if (choice == 'D') {
            window.open('http://espn.com','_self');
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working at all, Chrome included...  

Anything else you can see that could be causing this?

Comment: Works fine for me in IE... Comment your JSFiddle here

Comment: The `action` attribute accepts a URL, and `javascript:` ends up becoming a protocol identifier similar to http or https. IE seems to interpret this fine, but this really isn't part of the ECMA spec so browser support may become spotty. Instead, use `action="#" onsubmit="..."`.

Comment: Change `return: false;` to `return false;`

Comment: Other than that, everything looks fine on my end. Try the other browsers you mentioned

Comment: @imbondbaby I'm testing this exact code on IE 11 and it's not working.

Comment: Changed the JS on the edit... Your value for choice was not coming up

Answer (score 0):

Your `onsubmit` handler needs to return false, or accept an `event` argument and cancel the submit event.

```
<form onsubmit="return OpenWindow()" id="page1" action="#" method="post">

function OpenWindow() {
    // ...
    return false;
}
```

Don't forget the `#` as the value for the `action` attribute on the form.